# Member Function Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, function-pointers

I'm trying to retrieve a boolean value from one of two member functions. I would like to call a member function(main) that will point to one of two member functions based on a value passed to main...here is what I have so far:

```
    class CRoutine{

    ...
    BOOL (*MainRoutine(BOOL opcode))();
    static BOOL SubRoutine1();
    static BOOL SubRoutine2();
    ...
    };

    BOOL (*CRoutine::MainRoutine(BOOL opcode))()
    {   
        switch ( opcode )
        {
        case false:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Routine1", L"Routine1", MB_OK);
            return &CRoutine::SubRoutine1;
        case true:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Routine2", L"Routine2", MB_OK);
            return &CRoutine::SubRoutine2;
        default:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Default Routine Selected", L"Routine1", MB_OK);
            return &CRoutine::SubRoutine1;
        }
    }

    BOOL CRoutine::SubRoutine1()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Routine1", L"Routine1", MB_OK);
        return true;
    }
    BOOL CRoutine::SubRoutine2()
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Routine2", L"Routine2", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    winMain(...)
    {
    ...
 m_routine = new CRoutine();
    BOOL result = m_routine->MainRoutine(0);
    ...
    }
```

My question is:

How do I call MainRoutine() in order to get the boolean value from SubRoutine1() or SubRoutine2(). When I run the program as is I get the following error:

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'BOOL'

This is mostly theory I'm interested in, I know there are other ways of getting such a simple answer...thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `bool` implicitly as `int` and vice versa probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: C++ has a real `bool`ean type; why are you using a `BOOL` macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
BOOL result = m_routine->MainRoutine(0)();
```

It is because you return function pointer from `MainRoutine(0)`, thus you need another pair of parentheses to invoke the function pointed by it.

---

By the way, you are returning plain function pointer, not a member function pointer.

Comment: how do you mean? in MainRoutine?

Comment: @P.Avery Yes. But it is ok, plain function pointers are used to store pointer to static member function.

Comment: thanks for the help, I can run program with fewer conditional statements now

Comment: @P.Avery you're welcome, by the way: up-voting and accepting answer is a way to say "thanks" at this site. :)